# Finding the contiguous sequences of equal elements in a list Raku

Tags: sequence, raku

I'd like to find the contiguous sequences of equal elements (e.g. of length 2) in a list

```
my @s = <1 1 0 2 0 2 1 2 2 2 4 4 3 3>;
say grep {$^a eq $^b}, @s;

# ==> ((1 1) (2 2) (4 4) (3 3))
```

This code looks ok but when one more **2** is added after the sequence of `2 2 2` or when one **2** is removed from it, it says `Too few positionals passed; expected 2 arguments but got 1` How to fix it? Please note that I'm trying to find them without using `for` loop, i.e. I'm trying to find them using a functional code as much as possible.

*Optional:* In the bold printed section:

`<1 1 0 2 0 2 1` **2 2 2** `4 4 3 3>`

multiple sequences of `2 2` are seen. How to print them the number of times they are seen? Like:

```
((1 1) (2 2) (2 2) (4 4) (3 3))
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are an even number of elements in your input:

```
say elems <1 1 0 2 0 2 1 2 2 2 4 4 3 3>; # 14
```

Your `grep` block consumes two elements each time:

```
{$^a eq $^b}
```

So if you add or remove an element you'll get the error you're getting when the block is run on the single element left over at the end.

---

There are many ways to solve your problem.

But you also asked about the option of allowing for overlapping so, for example, you get two `(2 2)` sub-lists when the sequence `2 2 2` is encountered. And, in a similar vein, you presumably want to see two matches, not zero, with input like:

```
<1 2 2 3 3 4>
```

So I'll focus on solutions that deal with those issues too.

Despite the narrowing of solution space to deal with the extra issues, there are still many ways to express solutions functionally.

---

One way that just appends a bit more code to the end of yours:

```
my @s = <1 1 0 2 0 2 1 2 2 2 4 4 3 3>;
say grep {$^a eq $^b}, @s .rotor( 2 => -1 ) .flat
```

The [`.rotor` method](https://docs.raku.org/routine/rotor#(List)_method_rotor) converts a list into a list of sub-lists, each of the same length. For example, `say <1 2 3 4> .rotor: 2` displays `((1 2) (3 4))`. If the length argument is a pair, then the key is the length and the value is an offset for starting the next pair. If the offset is negative you get sub-list overlap. Thus `say <1 2 3 4> .rotor: 2 => -1` displays `((1 2) (2 3) (3 4))`.

The [`.flat` method](https://docs.raku.org/routine/flat#(Iterable)_method_flat) "flattens" its invocant. For example, `say ((1,2),(2,3),(3,4)) .flat` displays `(1 2 2 3 3 4)`.

A perhaps more readable way to write the above solution would be to omit the `flat` and use `.[0]` and `.[1]` to index into the sub-lists returned by `rotor`:

```
say @s .rotor( 2 => -1 ) .grep: { .[0] eq .[1] }
```

See also Elizabeth Mattijsen's comment for another variation that generalizes for any sub-list size.

---

If you needed a more general coding pattern you might write something like:

```
say @s .pairs .map: { .value xx 2 if .key < @s - 1 and [eq] @s[.key,.key+1] }
```

The [`.pairs` method on a list](https://docs.raku.org/routine/pairs#class_List) returns a list of pairs, each pair corresponding to each of the elements in its invocant list. The `.key` of each pair is the index of the element in the invocant list; the `.value` is the value of the element.

`.value xx 2` could have been written `.value, .value`. (See [`xx`](https://docs.raku.org/routine/xx).)

`@s - 1` is the number of elements in `@s` minus 1.

The `[eq]` in `[eq] list` is a [reduction](https://docs.raku.org/language/operators#Reduction_metaoperators).

---

If you need text pattern matching to decide what constitutes contiguous equal elements you might convert the input list into a string, match against that using one of the match adverbs that generate a list of matches, then map from the resulting list of matches to your desired result. To match with overlaps (eg `2 2 2` results in `((2 2) (2 2))` use `:ov`:

```
say @s .Str .match( / (.) ' ' $0 /, :ov ) .map: { .[0].Str xx 2 }
```

Comment: It works quite fine. When I add 2 **2**s to make the sequence `2 2 2 2` it prints 3 `(2 2)`s which is as expected. Never heard of the method `rotor` I've initially come up with the `squish`method and checked if it has features or arguments like `@s.squish(:length 2, :multiple_instances yes)` but  it didn't have such features and it was no fit for the task. Compared with the `squish`, `rotor`  seems quite fit. Actually it might even be the fittest one for this type of operation.

Comment: `my $size = 2; say <1 1 0 2 0 2 1 2 2 2 4 4 3 3>.rotor( $size => -$size + 1).grep: { [eq] $_ }` #  ((1 1) (2 2) (2 2) (4 4) (3 3))

You only need to adjust the `$size` for different lengths of sequences.

Comment: Hi again @LarsMalmsteen. Please LMK if you think the two alternatives to `rotor` that I've added have weakened or strengthened my answer.

Comment: The refined version of the `rotor` solution i.e. `say @s.rotor(2=>-1).grep:{.[0]eq.[1]}` is welcome because it 's both shorter (by 3 to 5 chars depending on how the spaces are counted) and still looks decent. The generalized versions without the `rotor` method are welcome too because they show how some quirks like the `xx` and `:ov` are used. So the problem is very well solved :)

Answer (score 5):

TIMTOWDI!

Here's an iterative approach using `gather`/`take`.

```
say gather for <1 1 0 2 0 2 1 2 2 2 4 4 3 3> { 
    state $last = ''; 
    take ($last, $_) if $last == $_; 
    $last = $_; 
};

# ((1 1) (2 2) (2 2) (4 4) (3 3))
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. That looks quite fine in its own right. The `take ($last, $_)` part is a decent example on the usage of the `gather and take` duo.